# How do I say if a system is differentially flat?

Tags: mobile-robot

I am studying mobile robots, and I have encoutered the concept of differentially flat systems. I have seen that if a system is differentially flat, we can identify flat outputs, thanks to which we can reconstruct for example the inputs and the orientation.

For example, for a unycicle, the flat outputs are $x$ and $y$, and with them we can reconstruct the inputs  $v ,w$ , which are respectively the driving velocity and the steering velocity, and we can reconstruct the orientation $\theta $.

But, how do we know if a system is differentially flat? And basing on what do we identify the flat outputs?

I have understand what is a differentially flat system, but I don't know how to say if a given system is differentially flat or not, and if yes, I don't know how to identify the flat outputs.

Can somebody please help me?